# Why does "top: 50%; translateY(-50%);" create a lower gap than it should on certain elements within the same parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

I have this layout for my top-bar:

[image: Top-Menu]

All the elements should be vertically centered as per the design and here's my code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXGxWz

Unfortunately, the `top-bar_right-part` doesn't play nicely with the class `core_vertical-align` (notice how the left menu works) which does only this:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);
```

And as per the codepen, here's how it looks:

[image: Wrong Vertical align]
What is the issue here? *Additionally, the elements from the right part don't inherit the correct height (top-bar's), where as, the left menu does.*

Comment: Why not set `line-height` to be equal to the `height` of the main container?

Comment: @Ihazkode Smart decision. Or so I thought before. The problem with line-height is that as soon as you have two blocks of text below each other, you can't reset their inner line-heights, even with `!important` so, line-height is great for single line-elements, but impossible for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with different and better approach, I would use flexbox to 
vertically center elements in the navbar.
Set the parent of your elements to:
-display: flex;
-align-items: center;
It will align all your elements vertically to the center.
For more info:
[align-items center](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)

Comment: i second this, for aligning items vertically use flexbox, it is much more reliable and robust.

Comment: @cloned This is somewhat unrelated but I find flexbox unresponsive? In the sense that I can't seem to make it work, it can't resize its widths, any resources in that direction? I love flex, but boy, it seems it has issues.

Comment: what do you mean with resize the widths? you can set a width on the elements, a flex-basis for a width or set a different width for different breakpoints. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ this is the best summed up thing for flexbox i know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start of what is going on. The problem is that `position: absolute;` elements are placed according to the closest `position: relative;` parent.

So when you are trying to do the `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` it is centering the element vertically based on the size and location of the `.top-bar_right-part`.

I have linked to a changed pen that shows the elements (more) properly placed after adding `height: 100%` to line `16`. This sets the height of the right floating div to 100% of the parent, which in turn aligns the `position: absolute;` elements within it to the same size as the whole navigation. giving you a properly vertically centered item.

The main thing to remember here, is that when you area using an absolute element, it is positioned entirely based on the nearest relative parent. So make sure the relative parent is positioned properly as well as the absolute child.

**line 16-18 change:**
https://codepen.io/KyleCRat/pen/bYvWJz

Comment: Kyle. Thank you for your input. Are you saying that the `top: 50%;` transforms the element to an `absolute` element? Also, this method is supposed to be height agnostic, what am I missing here?

Comment: `top: 50%` moves the top of the absolutely positioned element to the vertical center of the `relative` element containing it. In your case the containing element is not 100% height of the main nav bar. So, your `top: 50%` is only centering it based on the height of the containing element within the nav bar.

I added a background color to the `.top-bar_right-part`, try adding and removing the `height: 100%` on that element to see how the size the container changes from covering the bar, to only covering about 60% of it to see if you can see what I'm talking about visually.